# How to set Condition = true by user response

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
Console.WriteLine("Unlike my deceased predecessor, A.I./Ai, I do not mind not being human. I am content with what I have.");
Console.ReadKey();
bool AI = false;
if (AI = true)
```

I want the user to type "AI" and have it set the bool to true if they do.

Comment: What key means true?

Comment: @TimSchmelter AI is the key

Comment: AI is two keys, no?

Comment: He means the actual key. Something has to trigger AI to change. What key, that the user presses on the keyboard, should update AI to true?

Comment: additionally, `if (AI = true)` will need to become `if (AI == true)` before it will work.

Comment: @Aaron What I meant is that I want them to type the word in and have it change the bool. ADyson thanks for the fix!

Comment: "type the word", I guess you need ReadLine instead of ReadKey then

Comment: What I'm saying is that I want the user to type AI and have that set the bool to true

Comment: You need a conditional check to do that. You are declaring a variable with the name AI, but that has nothing to do with the keys they type. You need to set a variable = Console.ReadLine(); and then check if the variable == "AI" and if it does, set AI = true;

Comment: @Aaron make an answer out of that. Is there a flag for 'clearly has learn the very basics of coding'?

Comment: @KamiKaze there was, but it was removed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason

Comment: How does the user know what to type if you haven't asked them a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading all the comments I think this is what you mean

```
Console.WriteLine("Unlike my deceased predecessor, A.I./Ai, I do not mind not being human. I am content with what I have.");

string answer = Console.ReadLine();

bool AI = (answer == "AI");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx). You also should make the check case insensitive in case the user enters `Ai` or `ai`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Unlike my deceased predecessor, A.I./Ai, I do not mind not being human. I am content with what I have.");
string lineRead = Console.ReadLine();
bool AI = "ai".Equals(lineRead, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(AI)
{
    // ai was selected
}
```